# Does closing questions prevent people from asking more?

Tags: support, closed-questions, asking-questions

I wanted to know if closing a question contributes towards people not being able to ask questions. Much like, if your questions get a lot of negative votes/ down votes you are not allowed to ask questions for a while till you get some up votes or get the heuristics right. So if my question is closed, does that mean that it contributes towards it?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does this also apply to meta too? I have not read it yet but have read the heading so sorry if my question sounds naive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, closed questions do seem to contribute. In fact, it is somewhat subtly implied in [the exact link users with a ban receive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) when they try to perform an action for which they have been banned.

Under "How do I avoid getting a question ban?" it states:

> So if many of your questions do not get any answer, are downvoted,
>   **closed**, or deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they
>   did not meet the required quality.

Based on this we can most likely assume that closed questions do factor in to the decision to ban or not.

The same general rules also apply for Meta SO. However, it seems the boundaries here are not as strict as on the main sites. The fact that downvotes on Meta are often used to indicate disagreement for example (rather than necessarily a bad question) would mean that users could rapidly end up being banned were we to apply the same rules, even though they really shouldn't be.

The exact boundaries are however unknown to most of us.

Comment: It doesn't say anything in that post about closed questions affecting the filter.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "if many of your questions do not get any answer, are downvoted, **closed**, or deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they did not meet the required quality." Though perhaps that's too subtle...

Comment: Mmm.  There is an implication there, I agree.  But the post also states that none of us are privvy to the exact details of how the filter works.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've updated my answer. Thanks for the heads-up though.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that those few people here who do know, can't/won't tell you, so no matter what, you won't be told.

Comment: I know downvotes and self-deleted posts count specifically against you. I don't think closed posts do; that list also says "if many of your questions did not get any answer"; it's just trying to cue you in that "yeah, your questions kinda suck". I've never heard of *unanswered questions* counting against you of course.

Comment: @BenBrocka Why would closed posts not factor in?